# how to run apex in user context

Tags: executioncontext

We have integration between two modules and both are complete custom apex code . Module-1 need to call Module-2 logic via interface class . Is it possible to run module-2 logic in different specific user context ?
We wanted to run the module in specific user context to bypass triggers, workflow rules etc

Answer (score 2):

If "asynchronous" (or at least "out of transaction") execution of module 2 from module 1 is acceptable, you could have module 1 initiate module 2 via a platform event that is consumed by a trigger running as a specific user. (You can hide the platform event creation and publication in a method on module 1 that looks just like the one you want to call on module 2).

The steps would be:

1. Define a special platform event representing the module 2 API invocation, with fields that represent the parameters to the call.
2. Define a platform event subscriber as an Apex platform event trigger. This unpacks the event's fields and calls the module 2 API with the parameters.
3. If use of the "Automated Process" user isn't enough distinction for you, define the platform event subscriber user via the [PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm) for this platform event.
4. Have module 1 create and publish a platform event record populated with the required parameter values when it wants to call module 2.

All of this would be part of module 2, except the initial event creation and publication.

Answer (score 1):

You can set static variables that hold their state within a transaction. So with the two modules both referencing such a variable, Module-1 can set it and then Module-2 can read it to perform the necessary logic. (This is just a backdoor way to pass the state into the called code; you could pass it directly.)

Triggers can reference static variables, so you can make those execute conditionally.

There is no simple way to switch user across a method call; only the Apex test environment supports `System.runAs(user)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Hierarchical Custom Setting, with a Lookup to User, and insert a ByPass trigger data in this custom setting right at the start of module 2 for the current User only.

And then delete this custom setting at the end of your whole process.

`CustomSetting` can be inserted via apex and can be used in this scenario.
But all your workflows, validations and Triggers needs a condition check, that of the data is added in the custom setting then don't run these.